# Good references on Riemannian Geometry

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I'd like a textbook that covers do Carmo's contents (can be more), but that isn't do Carmo. I did not like his writting style. That being said, I particularly like the styles of:

Walter Rudin (Principles of Mathematical Analysis and Real and Complex Analysis)

Bredon (Topology and Geometry)

Munkres (Topology)

And in order to further specify, I like concise textbooks that go directly to the subject and prove the results in an efficient manner.

Thank you.

Comment: if you would like a totally different viewpoint on this topic i would recommend the appropriate chapters in "geometry and topology and physics" by Nakahara.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last comment suggests that you may like *Riemannian Geometry* by Petersen, but I personally find it difficult to read. From what I understand, it covers more than do Carmo does and it is useful beyond a first course in the subject.

Another book that is worth checking out is Lee's *Riemmanian Manifolds*; note though that it doesn't cover the latter parts of do Carmo's book in as much detail. As with his *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, Lee is incredibly clear in his exposition and I find it very easy to read.

Comment: Thank you for helping! I checked out Petersen's. I didn't go thoroughly through the text, but I should say that I also like the "Definition - Theorem" format, which is not Petersen's apparently.

Answer (score 0):

You may check these ones:

(i)  Riemannsche Geometrie im Grossen (D. Gromoll, W. Klingenberg, W. Meyer). It's a bit old and in german but it is good.

(ii) An Introduction to Riemannian Geometry (L. Godinho, J. Natario). This is pretty recent and sounds cool but it is a bit elementary. I has also applications in Relativity.

(iii) Riemannian Geometry - A Modern Introduction (I. Chavel).

There is another one also in german which is a lot good but I don't recall its title right now but I'll check and add later.